# MailMerge - Excel (data) into Word (template) - With OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml, mailmerge

I tried a lot of time to fine a simple and elegane way to do 
a mailmerge by openXML.

Am I supposed to work through the XML file? Or is it another way
?
I have seen several different solutions, but none have given me a comlete solution.
(I need the TAMPLATE to be duplicated by the amount of data.
For example, if I have 300 rows in Excel, and I have one page in the WORD template - I need it will be duplicated to 300 pages).

Does anyone have a complete solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to use OpenXML SDK then you should realize that everything is done through XML with it. In other words, you should be accustomed to XML manipulation if you're going with this path. Nevertheless, you could check out [DocumentAssembler](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/documentassembler-developer-center/) module from [OpenXML SDK PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools), it should help you out with this task.